# Was Asgard ever invaded by Galactus?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, galactus

I haven't come across any comic books about this (as far as I've read) but, by any chance, did ***Galactus ever invade Asgard***? If yes, what was the outcome? How was Asgard saved from the Devourer of Worlds?

PS: I welcome any reading suggestions (if any) related to this topic too.

Comment: In Last Planet Standing he does. You can read the rest in the plot section on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Planet_Standing

Comment: He also does in What If: Featuring Thor, or whatever the title is: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/What_If:_Thor_Vol_1_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the details provided by J Doe, I was able to collect some information.

In the five-issue mini series "***Last Planet Standing***", Galactus did invade and consume Asgard.

[image: Cover page of Issue # 1: Last Planet Standing]

One of Galactus's heralds: Dominas-the Wavemaster enters the Shi'ar Imperial Throneworld and wreaks havoc. After completely overthrowing the imperial guards,  Galactus is summoned. Despite the efforts, Galactus's elemental converter drains the planet dry and the once well-known planet now is left lifeless. Galactus then reveals to his herald Dominas that he no longer desires to merely sate his hunger; he now wishes to gather energy with the intention of evolving to the next level. And to do so, he need to consume the eternal realm of Asgard itself.

Dominas attacks Asgard where he faces Thor. Thor leads his mighty warriors into battle against Galactus's herald. During the battle, the Asgardians are defeated, and Thor is taken prisoner (He was later made into a hearld of Galactus in a What if storyline mentioned [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/What_If:_Thor_Vol_1_1)). Dominas then retrieves the Over-sword. According to Marvel:

> *It is a special weapon; a giant-sized sword that, if ever unsheathed, it was said, that* "***the end of the universe is at hand***".

With the help of the Over-sword (also called the Odinsword), Galactus absorbs the life-force holding the eternal realm. And so falls Asgard: The Realm Eternal, the Golden Realm.

Comment: So, did Galactus evolve into Galactizard?

Comment: @Ellesedil - In *THE ULTIMATES* (2015-2016), he became Galactus the Life-Bringer, and started bringing new life to worlds he had previous consumed all the energy from. This is in the main Marvel comics reality. Thor and Asgard were not involved.